# Export all not in comparison table

Tags: t-sql, common-table-expression

I have been using the following export query (CTE) for a few years but a client has requested that we do not give them all of the data from the 'C' line as they do not need some of the data.  I have all of the PlaintiffNames that they do not need but I have no idea how to adjust the query to exclude the PlaintiffNames they do not need. And using NOT IN as is shown below has not worked and I am guessing I am missing something!

```
SELECT 4 AS grpOrd
    , null AS posInGrp
    , 'C'
    , A.CaseNumberKey
    , 'C|' + IsNull(J.CType, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.plaintiffName,'') + '|' + IsNull(J.plaintiffAdd1, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.plaintiffCity, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.plaintiffState, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.plaintiffZip, '') + '|' + '|' + IsNull(J.defendantName, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.defendantAdd1, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.defCity, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.defState, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.defZip, '') + '|' +  '|' + IsNull(J.Court, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.CaseID, '') + '|' + IsNull(J.JAmt, '') + '|' + IsNull(replace(convert(VarChar(10), JDate, 101), '/', ''), '') + '|' + IsNull(replace(convert(VARCHAR(10), revivedDate, 101), '/', ''), '') AS Extract
FROM   newCityCollection.dbo.PropertyInformation A 
JOIN   Acme.new_judgment_system.dbo.selected_compiled_clean J 
    ON J.CaseNumber = A.CaseNumberKey
WHERE  A.DateFinished BETWEEN @PeriodStart AND @PeriodEnd 
    AND ClientKey = 2 
    AND (J.plaintiffName NOT IN (SELECT Plaintiff FROM dbo.excluded_Plaintiffs))
```

I am getting invalid object name `dbo.excluded_Plaintiffs` when I try to run this.  Note that is the very bottom of the CTE which has numerous lines but the issue is solely in this last line.

An example of a common plaintiff that they do not want is `'PHILA TRAFFIC COURT'`

Is it possible to adjust the above to check the table (excluded_Plaintiffs) and exclude that data?  I have tried to no avail and am hoping someone has the answer.

Comment: Please post exact error message.

Comment: I notice that one FROM clause includes a fully qualified database.schema.table name, but the other FROM clause is only schema.table.  Could it be that you're running the query against a database that doesn't have the table dbo.excluded_plaintiffs ?

Comment: @Triple I figured that out just as you did based on times tamps anyway!  I hate when I make silly mistakes like that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I answered my own question.  I missed the database in this line dbo.excluded_Plaintiffs.  Should be written newCityCollection.dbo.excluded_Plaintiffs.